# How to customize tooltip in SilverLight Teletik GanttView?

Tags: silverlight, telerik, gantt-chart

I use Telerik GanttView Control in my SilverLight project. It genral the chart well. And I want change the tooltip of the task with my own data in ViewModel. How to change it? Someone has idea?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [GanttView - FirstLook](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#GanttView/FirstLook) demo to get started with GanttView + MVVM scenario.

Comment: I have read the example's code. Did not find where customize the tooltip of the task.